# Unable to view the content of a fixed div loaded inside iframe. How can we show scroll for a div with position FIXED and loaded inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, iframe

Unable to view the content of a fixed div loaded inside iframe. How can we show scroll for a div with position FIXED and loaded inside iframe?

I have to load a URL inside iframe. The problem here is , the content inside iframe has a modal pop up which will appear on click of one button. So when  load initially the iframe content looks good. But when  clicked on button then the half of the modal pop up is visible. The position of modal div is fixed. Which we can not change as we are just loading the URL inside iframe.

```
<div class="classiframe"><iframe src="urlofsite"></iframe></div>
```

Css:

```
.classiframe{
padding-top: 0;
position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you supply the src attribute actual value to see the issue so that you get better help